# How to set minimum-container-ttl-duration in yml

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to set the `minimum-container-ttl-duration` property on a Kubernetes CronJob. I see a bunch of properties like this that appear to be configurable, but the documentation doesn't appear to show where, in the yml file, they can actually be set.

In this example yml, where would I put this property?

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`minimum-container-ttl-duration` is not a property on `CronJob` but **is a Node-level property** set via a command line parameter: `kubelet ... --minimum-container-ttl-duration=x`.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/#user-configuration:

> `minimum-container-ttl-duration`, minimum age for a finished container before it is garbage collected. Default is 0 minute, which means every finished container will be garbage collected.

The usage of this flag is deprecated.

Comment: Darn. This isn't useful to me at all then.